# Expected value of cross tabulation / contigency table

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus, means

I’ve got a pretty interesting problem and I can’t figure out how to address it. I can’t even find a similar problem on the internet.

I have a cross tabulation / contigency table like this:

|  | 72251100 | 72255090 | 72259200 |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ITAPOLIS |  |  |  | 828,339 |
| PIRACICABA |  |  |  | 1,543,919 |
| BIRIGUI |  |  |  | 536,795 |
|  | 1,365,134 | 1,175,953 | 367,966 |  |

I know the margins, but I don’t know its cells.

Besides that,I know that a few cells have the value equal to zero:

|  | 72251100 | 72255090 | 72259200 |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ITAPOLIS |  | 0 |  | 828,339 |
| PIRACICABA |  |  |  | 1,543,919 |
| BIRIGUI |  |  | 0 | 536,795 |
|  | 1,365,134 | 1,175,953 | 367,966 |  |

The questions is:

How do I calculate the expected value (or weight mean) of this contigency table given I have two zeros ??

Comment: Please clarify the question. We computed the expected value of a random variable. What is the random variable in question?

Comment: On the left are the states of a country and on the top are codes of products.

If I had no zeros, we would be like that: The expected value for each cell is calculated by multiplying the row total by the column total, then dividing by the grand total.

Comment: Oh, sounds like you are referring to the expected frequency in the context of a chi square test of independence? In any case, the table is not uniquely determined; you need to know the value of at least $(r-1)(c-1)=4$ cells (the degrees of freedom) to pin it down.

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm that you want is called *Iterative Proportional Fitting.*

You'll probably want to initialize it using the **same** value for each of the unknown elements, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
&A_0 = \pmatrix{1&0&1\\1&1&1\\1&1&0}
}$$
The other inputs are the marginal totals:

$\qquad$ one vector $(x)$ for the row totals and another $(y)$ for the column totals

After about a dozen iterations you'll arrive at
$$A_{12} = \pmatrix{628,650 & 0 & 199,689 \\
529,763 & 845,879 & 168,277 \\
206,721 & 330,074 & 0 \\}$$
Changing $A_0$ will generate a different solution, but the above is the max entropy solution.

---

Here is the pseudo-code for the algorithm

```
do
   B  =  A .* (x*u') ./ (A*u*u')
   A  =  B .* (u*y') ./ (u*u'*B)
until norm(A-B) < tolerance
```

where `x,y` are the target row/column sum vectors and `u` is the all-ones vector. The operators `.*` and `./` denote elementwise multiplication/division, `*` is matrix multiplication, and an apostrophe `x'` denotes the transpose of `x`

Note that any zeros in the initial $A$ matrix will propagate through to the solution matrix, because of those elementwise multiplications.

Comment: Thank you very much, @greg!!!! This is exactly what I was looking for